# I accidentally added ridiculously huge amount of rows in PHPMyAdmin database table and some PHPMyadmin features got disabled

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I accidentally wrote a code with infinity loop, and added A LOT OF ROWS IN A TABLE. The loop ran for around 20-60 sec (not sure).

So, i tried to `TRUNCATE "lastrequestdone";` but, it is not working. I still the same amount of rows in the table.

I tried to drop the table and re-create it, but i found out the rows still exist even after dropping the table and recreating it.

I also started to get this message in `PHPMyAdmin`

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
> Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

and when i click on "find out why"

I get this message

> Configuration of pmadb… not OK
>
> General relation features Disabled
>
> Create a database named 'phpmyadmin' and setup the phpMyAdmin configuration storage there.

PHP is really fast, I have no idea, how many rows i added....

P.S: I tried to drop and re-create the table again after 10 minutes, and it is empty now. Sorry for rushing to stackoverflow, I was scared to death.

But, I still get those error in yellow background above.

Comment: "it is not working" is not an accurate problem description. `TRUNCATE` is generally the appropriate tool to 'remove all rows, and leave the table', and there is also `DELETE`..

Comment: Not working means, the table is not empty. Also read the P.S part, I edited the quesiton

Comment: TRUNCATE will "very much work" if it doesn't raise an error; *except* if in a TRANSACTION that has been *rolled back*. Perhaps there are two *different* tables with the same/similar name in different schemas?

Comment: Next time take a backup of your database before such an operation.

Comment: This sounds like there is insufficient separation between development and production.

Comment: I'll reiterate what Luis is saying: **ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS make backups before important operations**. As they say, if you don't have backups of your database you don't have a database, you have a liability.

Comment: The triage option.... "Unsalvageable"...The wording gets a whole new dimensions in context with OP's problems. I'd vote for a new badge **"Self Fulfilling Prophecy"** ;-)